# Is To Catch a Thief based on an adventure (other than Dragon Heist)?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

I have [Escape the Underdark](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/fiction/childrens-books-novels/escape-underdark), and (as far as I can tell) it is based on [Out of the Abyss](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/outoftheabyss). I also have [To Catch a Thief](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/fiction/childrens-books-novels/catch-thief), but it seems to share little with [Waterdeep: Dragon Heist](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/dragonheist) other than the setting. I saw [A Tale of Two Fishies](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/254526/Waterdeep-A-Tail-of-Two-Fishies) on Dungeon Masters Guild, but I don't have it myself. Is To Catch a Thief actually based on this latter adventure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Unlikely.

The DM's Guild module you've linked to is neither an official product, nor is it written by the same person.

The *[Endless Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_Quest#Endless_Quest_(2018-9))* books are official *Wizards of the Coast* products, with the two you've linked and a handful of others in the current run written by [Matt Forbeck](https://www.amazon.com/Matt-Forbeck/e/B000APS9SU/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1). They have thematic ties to WotC's hardcover adventure releases, but not necessarily strong plot ties.

In fact, the ones you've linked are only the most recent incarnation of *Endless Quest*. A [much earlier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_Quest) was written for TSR, starting with *[Dungeon of Dread](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0935696865)* by [Rose Estes](https://www.amazon.com/Rose-Estes/e/B001HOLQAG/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1) in 1982. There were nearly 50 books in this series - 36 released in the '80s and 11 released in the '90s (with two unreleased), though they weren't all D&D based.